# Why are my LED lights flashing when powered from an inverter?

Tags: lighting, led

I am running some 10 watt LED floodlights off a 12 volt battery and 230 volt inverter. 
The 10 watt LED floodlights are flashing on and off. I am also running 20 watt floodlights and they do not flash. Both work perfectly on the mains power.

How can I eliminate the flashing with the 10W lights?

Comment: What are the specs of the inverter?  Does it output a stable 50/60hz true sine wave?  Most likely it doesn't put out a true sine wave and some electronics can't handle that.

Comment: You are converting from low-voltage DC to high-voltage AC and then back to low-voltage DC. It might be worth considering converting your LED floodlights to work directly from an external low-voltage DC supply without two intermediate conversions.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a better inverter. The DC/AC circuits in your 10W lights evidently like a pure sine wave (as provided by grid/mains power) on the AC input side, and your inverter is almost certainly not a pure sine wave inverter (just based on your symptoms, but feel free to confirm/deny).

Comment: +1 and also: I would guess that they might be dimmable LED floodlights, and their circuitry that looks for the duty cycling from the dimmer is being confused by the waveform from the inverter.

Answer (score 1):

On my installation, the dimmable led lights (15 out of 17 circuits) would flash when running from solar backup (Tesla battery) or from the generator. Both are sine wave.

I finally diagnosed it as voltage. The grid is 225 to 227 volts. But both the Generator and Solar are 240 volts. I know that it defies logic because the led drivers are converting it to DC. But I have no other explanation.

So, I ended up removing the dimmers, and all is good.